# How to create a simple 3 for 2 campaign using built-in PHP functions?

Tags: php

I'm a complete beginner at PHP and I'd like to create a simple 3 for 2 campaign with the help of built in functions (such as i.e array_pop(), array_sum() or something else) and I've unfortunately hit a wall.

I've created an array with completely made up pizzas:

```
$pizzaArray = [
    "Hackaton" => [
        "price" => 135,
        "ingredients" => "tomato sauce and magic",
        "randomComment" => "tastes like unicorns"
    ],
    "Plug-in" => [
        "price" => 145,
        "ingredients" => "sardeler och oliver",
        "randomComment" => "Ripasso"
    ],
    "Lulz" => [
        "price" => 150,
        "ingredients" => "tomato sauce and old socks",
        "randomComment" => "tastes like old socks"
    ]
];
```

Please don't mind the weird values. The only thing that is "important" are the price arrays.
What I basically want to achieve is that if a customer were to purchase 3 pizzas, then the $totalSum will equal the total amount minus the cheapest pizza.
I'm trying to think that it'd be achieveable if I were to be able to code this:

```
$numberOfPizzas = count($pizzaarray);
$totalSum = 0;
if ($numberOfPizzas == 3) {
    //array_pop() the cheapest pizza
    // $totalSum =array_sum() price of remaining pizza

} else { 
    //$totalSum = array_sum() prices of all pizzas
```

But since I can't really think like a programmer yet my head simply won't output something that is logical. Could this be achieved in a simple scenario?

Comment: What if someone orders 6 pizzas, do they only pay for the 4 most expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/uasort) to sort the pizzas by price, then [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) to take all but the cheapest, then [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) to compute the final price:

```
$pizzas = [
  'Hackaton' => ['price' => 135, 'ingredients' => 'tomato sauce and magic', 'randomComment' => 'tastes like unicorns'],
  'Plug-in' => ['price' => 145, 'ingredients' => 'sardeler och oliver', 'randomComment' => 'Ripasso'],
  'Lulz' => ['price' => 150, 'ingredients' => 'tomato sauce and old socks', 'randomComment' => 'tastes like old socks']
];

uasort($pizzas, static function (array $pizza1, array $pizza2): int {
  return $pizza1['price'] <=> $pizza2['price'];
});

$pizzasMinusCheapest = array_slice($pizzas, 1);
// or, if you want the discount to apply for every 3 pizzas,
// $pizzasMinusCheapest = array_slice($pizzas, (int)(count($pizzas) / 3)) 

$finalPrice = array_reduce($pizzasMinusCheapest, static function (int $total, array $pizza): int {
  return $total + $pizza['price'];
}, 0);

echo $finalPrice;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/gYKdY**

Bonus - using PHP 7.4's short closures:

```
uasort($pizzas, fn(array $pizza1, array $pizza2): int => $pizza1['price'] <=> $pizza2['price']);
$pizzasMinusCheapest = array_slice($pizzas, 1);
$finalPrice = array_reduce($pizzasMinusCheapest, fn(int $total, array $pizza): int => $total + $pizza['price'], 0);
```

Comment: I do think it's apropos to use `array_slice` on pizzas!